# Conditional Formatting in Excel selecting wrong rows when trying to highlight cells greater than 15

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to highlight cells that are greater than 15. But it's highlighting all of the cells in the row. I have a formula in the row so I do not know if that is messing with it. The formula is:

`=IFERROR(IF(E7="","0", IF(NETWORKDAYS(E7,O7,MenuData!$G$3:$G$22)<0, "0", (NETWORKDAYS(E7,O7,MenuData!$G$3:$G$22)-1))),0)`

I select the entire column that I want to apply the conditional formatting, select highlight cell rules.> greater than > and then put for it to select cells greater than 15 and to highlight them red. It then highlights everything greater than 15 but also selects the zeros that are 0 due to the if/iferror statements in the formula.

Comment: Try to use `0` as a number instead of `"0"` as string in all cases.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not realize that putting the double quotes around the 0 made it a non-numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formula you can also use Conditional Formatting.

1. Go to Home Tab.
2. Select the area you want to format. In your case Area is
3. Select "CONDITIONAL FORMATTING" from the Menu.
4. Select  "NEW RULE".
5. Select  option " Format Only Cells that contain value...”.
6. From Drop Down Tabs select : " Cell Value " , " Greater than" , 15  "
7. Format as you want Colour, Fill etc.

Comment: I have improved the formatting of this answer but it seems incomplete.